# How change generate token path in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to change url `/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials` to `/mytext/token?grant_type=client_credentials`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the endpoint for the client system then Yes, but in that case you've to create an api, mapping to address `/mytext/token` for the clients. Provide all the details from client-end that require for `client_credentials` grant type. Once your server received the request, you can use those details and invoke the endpoint `/oauth2/token` of the `Authorization server`.